# Limit number of decimals displayed for input tag in html viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

I have an asp.net core MVC application that, among other, display values in readonly input fields within a `cshtml` view.  The fields are obtained from a model.  I would like to limit the number of decimals displayed for a `double` property, but am only successful in doing so for a `decimal` property, by applying the attribute as shown below.

Model:

```
public class RectangleModel
{

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n3}")]
    public double Length { get; private set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n3}")]
    public double Width { get; private set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n3}")]
    public decimal Area { get; private set; }

}
```

View:

```
@model PathTo.Models.RectangleModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RectangleAreaGenerator";
}

<h1>Rectangle area generator</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="RectangleAreaGenerator">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Width" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Width" class="form-control" readonly />
                <label asp-for="Length" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Length" class="form-control" readonly />
                <label asp-for="Area" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Area" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code renders a view that looks as follows (example):
[image: Example of view output]

Is there a way to also limit the number of decimals displayed for `double`s similar to `decimal`s?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution eventually...  It seems that an input field in cshtml (even if specified as readonly) is always observed as editable from the `DisplayFormat` property attribute.  Hence, also specifying `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` solved the problem.  For completeness sake, an example of the full property attribute are as follows:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n3}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public double Area { get; private set; }
```

Why I do not need to specify `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` to a `decimal`, but have to for a `double` property, is still unknown to me.  Perhaps someone can provide an answer to this?